# Evaluate $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2-1}$ over $|z-1|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate evaluate $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2-1}$ over $|z-1|=1$ without any more machinery than the definition of a complex path integral.

Parameterizing the path as $\gamma(t)=1+e^{it}$

$$
\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z-1}-\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z+1}\right)
=\pi i-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it}+2}\;dt
$$

Now I'm unsure about the evaluation of this last integral. Since it's a real integral, I think we can just use that it has an antiderivative of $\log(e^{it}+2)$ to get that the last integral is 0, but I'm not certain about that. Do I need to be considering a branch of the logarithm or be worried about that here?

Comment: You need to consider the branch cut, and then it turns out that $e^{it} + 2$ never touches the principal branch cut. So you are safe to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second integral is a complex *valued* integral over the real line.  You can pick whatever branch of the logarithm you'd like and the result will be well-defined (and zero).

In general, you only need to be concerned when you integrate from one side of the branch cut to the other side, but you should be able to see that this doesn't happen when you integrate outward along the real line.